# Contact form stuck at loading

Tags: php, html

I'm having issues with my contact form hoping someone can help. It just sits there stuck at 'loadiing' when I click 'send'.  I was able to send at one point and then tried to get the phone number to send and now nothing is working. As far as I can tell things are pointing to the correct places. What am I missing?

www.krjwoodcraft

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$mobile = $_POST['url'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$sender = $_POST['email'];
$message= $_POST['message'].' <br>Mobile: '.$_POST['url'].'  ';


  $your_site_name = "www.krjwoodcraft.com";
  $your_email = "rob.catharsis@gmail.com";   


// setting header:
$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header .= "From: {$name} <{$sender}>\r\n";

//   to       subject               message       header
$result = mail($your_email, "Message from ".$your_site_name, nl2br($message), $header);
echo "Your Message has been sent";

?>
```

## contact.html

```
<!-- Contact Form -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="trac_contactform">
                    <form id="contact_form" class="row" name="form1" method="post" action="send.php">
                        <div class="span6">
                            <input type="text" class="full" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                            <div id="error_name" class="error">Please check your name</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="span6">
                            <input type="text" class="full" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                            <div id="error_email" class="error">Please check your email</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="span6">
                            <input type="text" class="full" name="url" id="url"  placeholder="Phone Number"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="span6">
                            <input type="text" class="full" name="subject" id="subject"  placeholder="Subject"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="span12">
                            <textarea cols="10" rows="10" name="message" id="message" class="full"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            <div id="error_message" class="error">Please check your message</div>
                            <div id="mail_success" class="success">Thank you. Your message has been sent.</div>
                            <div id="mail_failed" class="error">Error, email not sent</div>
                            <p id="btnsubmit">
                                <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send Now" class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-embossed" /></p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: In regards to `$mobile = $_POST['url'];`?

Comment: Yeah if you fix that it should work fine.

Comment: this file gets server error 500 and can't post data to it : http://www.krjwoodcraft.com/send.php
that's why it's blocking

Comment: and your javascript function that send the post with ajax doesn't include the 'url' input in the data, but even with that you'll still get error 500 make sure you don't have a miss configured .htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, **my god man** this site loads slowly:

http://www.krjwoodcraft.com/

## Loading Content...

---

If everything was working prior to adding `$mobile = $_POST['url'];`, perhaps you are attaching the `data` improperly.

`<input type="text" class="full" name="url" id="url"  placeholder="Phone Number"/>`

Even this in and of itself, utilizing `url` as an `ID` is a bit weird to look at. Why not `ID phone`?

### Edit

> The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that
>   means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server
>   could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.

When I refresh the page, the form stops working entirely. Perhaps it has something to do with your validation code not sending the data?

#### After refreshing, it hangs here:

[image: Hanging]

Comment: it was a permissions issue. the file was set to be written by everybody. second time I had an issue on this site with hostgator default permissions.

Comment: I copied code above and now the mobile number is working. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

In your webpage contact.js you have the following which is great for a GET but not for a POST

```
data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + "You Got Email" + "&message=" + message,
```

But jquery is looking for a object form like the following

```
data: {name: name, email: email, subject: "You Got Email", message: message},
```

**EDIT:**

Also in your js you are only collecting `name`, `email`, `subject` and `message`. You aren't collecting `url` and in your send.php it is looking for `name`, `email`, `subject`, `message` AND `url` and you aren't checking if they are being sent and php is probably throwing a error: `… index url not found in …`

You should always check if POST/GET items are being sent don't always assume that they are sent all the time.

```
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], $_POST['url'])){
    #your email stuff
}
```

js:

```
var email  = $("#email").val();//add this at the top of your $("#send").click(function(){
data: {name: name, email: email, subject: "You Got Email", message: message, url: email},//and add url parameter
```